# Why is REST considered less coupled

Tags: rest

In the explanation of the differences between web services or (Web) APIs there seems to be agreement that REST results in a less coupled architecture.

For example:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-li-sdnrg-design-restapi-02 mentions that REST is suited for lowly coupled systems.
- https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/soap-vs-rest-comparing-two-apis/ states that SOAP is too highly coupled

What are the arguments for considering it less or lightly coupled?

Comment: Will possibly lead to opinionated answers, but not flagged as there's probably constructive factual arguments to be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a systems where clients aren't coupled to a specifiy service API, clients will in general be more failure tolerant and thus robust besides being usable for multiple RESTful APIs in general. They will adapt to changes done on the server side while a tightly coupled client will fail to process further requests.

In [REST API must be hypertext-driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) Fielding explained some of the constraints a RESTful architecture has and what could happend if an API fails to respect these rules.

As clients use links to interact with some remote server, a client has to have some knowledge on what a link is and what actions it can perform on it. This knowledge is in general defined by [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) (or any other transport protocol) and [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) specifications which are often built into the client by relying on certain frameworks or middleware. As links are a major part in REST and clients have to learn respective endpoints somehow Fielding referred to this in his blog post as:

> ... allow servers to instruct clients on how to construct appropriate URIs, such as is done in HTML forms and URI templates, by defining those instructions within media types and link relations.

though you see plenty of so-called "REST" services that do not support clients on this by not returning URIs at all or not keeping the semantics in the relation but put them into the URI. I.e. you will often see something like URIs like `http://some.server.com/api/v1/users/1234` which may give humans a clue of its purpose though if this "knowledge" is ported to a client, it might brake it easily if the server decides (or is instructed by someone) to change anything in the structure. If the server now moves the resource to i.e. `http://some.server.com/api/v1/employees/1234` the client wont be able to retrieve data of the user/employee any longer and thus break.

Instead the server should instruct the client with the needed information. It can add some redirect logic which upon invoking the former URI informs the client that the resource can now be found at the new location. The response from the server itself should name such a URI so a client can refer to a resource endpoint via the name instead of analyzing the URI. In HTML this can be achived like this: `<a href="http://some.server.com/api/v1/employees/1234" rel="user">Sam Sample</a>`. Instead of the client analyzing the URI for semantical structures, which also often leads to [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html), it simply uses what is given by the server and grasp the sense of the URI via the relational name `user` in the sample.

As HTTP (or any other transmission protocol used) allows to send almost any data between client and server, media types are used by server and clients in order to agree upon a data representation format both sides are able to understand and know how to process. The media type is therefore some kind of knowledge base of what to do with certain data. It can describe the syntactical structure of a document, the necessary elements to expect and the semantics each field has.

According to Fielding

> a REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. Any effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules for a media type

If you, however, take a close look at plenty of questions here at StackOverflow most messages are exchanged in plain JSON which does not convey any semantics about the actual data received nor does it hint the client on possible actions that can be performed on this data. [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) and similar media types at least provide some clue on resources and links a client can use in order to process further actions.

As the media type defines a client or server on how to process certain data, it might contain an indication that a link with a relation name like `user` references a user resource further data of that users can be retrieved from. If the URI of the resource is changed a RESTful client will still be able to process its task as it can deduct from the media type that the user information for a user can be retrieved via the relation name `user`. Where this URI is actually pointing at isn't of much relevance as the client will only invoke it to retrieve further data from.

As the question also targeted SOAP it is important to know that the SOAP API is very different to REST by nature. The tight coupling is defined via the WSDL contract which defines the server endpoint as well as the operations available to invoke as well as the parameter needed and response types to expect. If the server is adding or (re)moving certain parameters after a client implemented that contract that client will fail from sending further requests and hence needs to be updated before it can continue to work.

In this very simple scenario of letting the server move arround some resources it hopefully becomes clear that a client's knowledge is kept in media types and its state it is aquiring through interacting with the services rather than having it implemented in the code itself (like in SOAP or any propriatary Web-API client). The client is therefore not coupled to the API itself but to the media types which can be added dynamically.